# Error 57 :Attempt to read past end of file in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I wrote a fortran code to read data from a file stored as 2D array of complex variables and output on screen. But during execution an error message Error 57: Attempt to read past end-of-file.

```
PROGRAM IMPORTFILE

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER,    PARAMETER           :: DP = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,60)
COMPLEX(DP),DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE :: A,B
INTEGER             :: I,J,M,N

N = 12; M = 3

ALLOCATE(A(N,N),B(N,M))

OPEN(UNIT = 20, FILE ='C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\A_matrix.dat', &
    ACCESS='SEQUENTIAL', STATUS='OLD', FORM='FORMATTED')
DO I = 1,N  
    READ(20,FMT = '(2F20.10)')(A(I,J),J = 1,N)
END DO

OPEN(UNIT = 30, FILE ='C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\B_vector.dat',&
     ACCESS='SEQUENTIAL', STATUS='OLD', FORM='FORMATTED')
DO I = 1, N
    READ(30,FMT = '(2F20.10)')(B(I,J),J = 1, M)
END DO

DO J = 1, N
    WRITE(*,*) (B(J,I), I = 1,M)
END DO

DO J = 1, N
    WRITE(*,*) (A(J,I), I = 1,N)
END DO

CLOSE(20)

CLOSE(30)

END PROGRAM IMPORTFILE
```

Comment: Is `N` less than the number of lines in the files? Were `A` and `B` written to the file in the same exact manner as you are reading them?

Answer (score 0):

This format

```
  '(2F20.10)'
```

Says to read only 2 values. You need to put a repeat specifier as large or larger than your array,
eg:

```
 '(144F20.10)'
```

*Too big is* **ok..**, put 10000f20.10 if you need.
In f2008 you can specify unlimited repeat with *F20.10

(*..about time..*)

If that doesn't do the trick you should post a sample of what the data file looks like.